# Dividing a row into 4 columns which should be displayed same on mobile

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

How to divide a row into 4 columns and on mobile it should be like 2 rows with 2 columns each. Trying in angular 6

```
        <div class="row" id="info" *ngIf="this.details">
  <div class="col-md-12 mb-3" id="heading">
    <h3>Meeting Information</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
    <p class="msg">Resource Name</p>
    <p class="msg"> Resource Email</p>
    <p class="msg"> Contact</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <div>
      <p>: shammy</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>: shammy@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>: 7093241844 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
    <p class="msg">Meeting Title</p>
    <p class="msg">Meeting Feedback Link</p>
    <p class="msg">Meeting Time</p>
    <button class="cncl" name="Submit" type="Submit">Cancel Meeting</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <div>
      <p>: shammy</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>: shammy@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>: 7093241844 </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="resd" name="Submit" type="Submit">Reschedule Meeting</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is working good on pure HTML. When i see the responsiveness it is making 2 rows with 2 columns each. The same should work for my code in angular

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
 <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
 <p>Column 1</p>
 <p>Column 1</p>
 <p>Column 1</p>
 <p>Column 1</p>
 </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
  <p>Column 2</p>
  <p>Column 2</p>
  <p>Column 2</p>
  <p>Column 2</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
 <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
 <p>Column 3</p>
 <p>Column3</p>
 <p>Column 3</p>
 <p>Column 3</p>
 </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
  <p>Column 4</p>
  <p>Column 4</p>
  <p>Column 4</p>
  <p>Column 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried the same HTML in angular but it dosent work the same. It should divide into 2 rows with 2 columns each

Comment: consider using angular-flexlayout.

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

Answer (score 0):

I think inside the div with class `row`, each div should have a class of `col-xl-3 col-lg-3` to make it span in a single row on extra-large and lage devices and `col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6` to make it span in two rows on medium, small and extra-small devices.

Give this a try:

```
<div class="row" id="info" *ngIf="this.details">
  <div class="col-lg-12" id="heading">
    <h3>Meeting Information</h3>
  </div>


  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <p class="msg">Resource Name</p>
    <p class="msg"> Resource Email</p>
    <p class="msg"> Contact</p>
  </div>


  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div>
      <p>: shammy</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>: shammy@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>: 7093241844 </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <p class="msg">Meeting Title</p>
    <p class="msg">Meeting Feedback Link</p>
    <p class="msg">Meeting Time</p>
    <button class="cncl" name="Submit" type="Submit">Cancel Meeting</button>
  </div>


  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div>
      <p>: shammy</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>: shammy@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>: 7093241844 </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="resd" name="Submit" type="Submit">Reschedule Meeting</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4-cols-in-large-2-cols-in-medium-and-small?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="row" id="info" *ngIf="this.details">
  <div class="col-md-12 mb-3" id="heading">
  <h3>Meeting Information</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <p class="msg">Resource Name</p>
    <p class="msg"> Resource Email</p>
    <p class="msg"> Contact</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <p>: shammy</p>
    <p>: shammy@gmail.com</p>
    <p>: 7093241844 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <p class="msg">Meeting Title</p>
    <p class="msg">Meeting Feedback Link</p>
    <p class="msg">Meeting Time</p>
    <button class="cncl" name="Submit" type="Submit">Cancel Meeting</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <p>: shammy</p>
    <p>: shammy@gmail.com</p>
    <p>: 7093241844 </p>
    <button class="resd" name="Submit" type="Submit">Reschedule Meeting</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code works fine for me